# How to filter select from table by another table by exclusion principle

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My application under Spring Boot v1.5.7

I have 3 entities (schematically):

```
@Entity
public class Word {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id
    ...
}

@Entity
public class UserWordList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "word_id")
    private Word word;
}

@Entity
public class UserAnotherWordList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "word_id")
    private Word word;
}
```

And now I need to select all Words for User, but exclude Words placed in user's lists

Native SQL for user_id=1 is

```
select *
from  Word w
left join UserWordList uwl
    on w.id = uwl.word_id and uwl.user_id = 1
left join UserAnotherWordList uawl
    on w.id = uawl.word_id and uawl.user_id = 1
where uwl.word_id is NULL
and   uawl.word_id is NULL
```

What is a best way to do it? Ideally I would like to use Spring Data features or HQL, but I don't understand how...

**UPD**

I solve my problem with native query:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "User.getWordsToProcess",
    resultClass = Word.class,
    query = "<...native query to select Words...>"
)
public class User {...}

...

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    List<Word> getWordsToProcess(Integer userId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest answer is `Criteria` api (but that is deprecated in hibernate 5.2 and above.)
So you can use Hql :

```
getSession().createQuery(" select * from UserWordList u left join fetch u.word
left join fetch u.user").list()
```

And you can use `union` or create another query to fetch `UserAnotherWordList`.
Also you can set any restrictions in Hql like below:

```
Query query =  getSession().createQuery(" select * from UserWordList u left join fetch u.word left join fetch u.user us where us.user = :sample").list();
query.setParameter("sample",value);
query.list();
```

Comment: Just upvote. I had issue with i18n and your `left join fetch` helped me to solve my issue!